# js code does not work in html as a separate file (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

I have a really simple `Javascript` function (I'm not using `jQuery`) that works in `html` using the `<script>` tag, but it doesn't work when I put it in a separate `.js` file. I know I'm doing something wrong and it's probably just a simple fix, but I can't figure it out. Any help? Thank you very much!

Here's my js:

```
function create() {
  var htmlElements = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    htmlElements += '<div class="box">' + i + '</div>';
  }

  var container = document.getElementById("box");
  container.innerHTML = htmlElements;
}
```

and html:

```
 <head>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="box">
      <script>create();</script>
    </div>
 </body>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5hzA/129/

Comment: You need to include the external js files _before_ you call any functions in them.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I tried but it didn't work...

Comment: Meaning, you have to move where you define the function to be above where you call it.

Comment: I tried put <script src="main.js"></script> in <head> but it's not working

Comment: Please define _"not working"_. Also, update your question to match your code

Comment: @Phil  It's not outputing "01234" as it should. It did output "01234" when I put all the js code in html using <script>

Comment: try <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"> and make sure your html and js files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 5):

just move the row
`<script src="main.js"></script>`

above this
`<script>create();</script>`

**Please note**: during javascript exercises you should *always* check the javascript console (on Windows: press `Ctrl+Shift+J` in Firefox, `F12` button in Chrome)

Comment: just check the javascript console as I said.

Comment: I moved <script src="main.js"></script> to the head and checked the console, and it says "create is not defined", but I defined it...  @alfrefopacino

Comment: I just updated the question. Would you look it over? Thanks!

Comment: your code works, I guess you're making a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: it still doesn't work I update the question with a jsfiddle link

Comment: in your jsfiddle you use a file called `main.js` but you have no *external resource* with that name.

Comment: Also, with that fiddle the inline JS is wrapped inside a load event.. check the source of the result iframe. Change the load type to `no wrap - bottom of <head>`

Answer (score 1):

You are running create() before you have included external file, functions should run after you include external file